# multiple 'Unknown function implode on line 341' with htmlMimeMail

Tags: php, html, mime-mail

I have an art gallery client that has a small mailing list of their clients that they send an email invitation containing only a single image and an 'unsubscribe' line to every three weeks. The client also doesn't want the image to appear as an attachment. There has been a whole series of issues arising recently which has made this task extremely fraught so I have set up a structure to send the emails out via the web server. I am using Richard Heyes htmlMimeMail package to do this so that the image can be included. The image is first uploaded to the web server and is hard-coded to be re-named so that each upload overwrites the previous image.

The code all works absolutely fine if I do a test run to one recipient and a couple of Cc's. When I use the structure in a loop to send out multiple emails to around 1500 clients I suddenly get multiple `Unknown function implode on line 341` - the `prereg_match_all()` line - errors returned and some (or many) of the emails are not being sent out. I have tried various things, commenting out the `prereg_match_all` line and part of it, which stops the errors but then different issues arise each time such as the image not being included, and it still appears that some unknown number of the emails are not being sent.

I'm trying to understand if my coding of the loop is at fault or it is the `prereg_match_all()` function code which is at the root of the problem.

Any help at all gratefully received.

This is the unmodified code included in htmlMimeMail (which I licensed some years back). BTW Due to the limitations of version of PHP proved by the ISP on our shared hosting I'm unable to get later versions working and the various html mailing functions of PHP have also not been compiled in by the ISP.

```
/*
* Function for extracting images from  
* html source. This function will look  
* through the html code supplied by add_html()  
* and find any file that ends in one of the  
* extensions defined in $obj->image_types.  
* If the file exists it will read it in and  
* embed it, (not an attachment).  
*  
* @author Dan Allen  
*/  
function _findHtmlImages($images_dir)  
{  
    // Build the list of image extensions  
    while (list($key,) = each($this->image_types)) {  
        $extensions[] = $key;  
    }  

    preg_match_all('/(?:"|\')([^"\']+\.('.implode('|', $extensions).'))(?:"|\')/Ui', $this->html, $images);  

    for ($i=0; $i< count($images[1]); $i++) {  
        if (file_exists($images_dir . $images[1][$i])) {  
            $html_images[] = $images[1][$i];  
            $this->html = str_replace($images[1][$i], basename($images[1][$i]), $this->html);  
        }  
    }  

    if (!empty($html_images)) {  

        // If duplicate images are embedded, they may show up as attachments, so remove them.  
        $html_images = array_unique($html_images);  
        sort($html_images);  

        for ($i=0; $i< count($html_images); $i++) {  
            if ($image = $this->getFile($images_dir.$html_images[$i])) {  
                $ext = substr($html_images[$i], strrpos($html_images[$i], '.') + 1);  
                $content_type = $this->image_types[strtolower($ext)];  
                $this->addHtmlImage($image, basename($html_images[$i]), $content_type);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I'm getting the errors when this loop is used in the Send Email page.
`$user` and `$useremail` are hardcoded. `$subject` is set when the image upload file is used. `$body` and `$text` are created earlier in the Send Email page.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT ``client names`` AND ``email addresses`` FROM ``the database tables`` ORDER BY ``last``");  
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
$r=stripper($r); //included external function to stripslashes etc
$full=$r['first'].' '.$r['last'];
$em=trim($r['email']);

/* code from htmlMimeMail package */

$mail_1->setHTML($body, $text, '');
$mail_1->setReturnPath("$user <$useremail>");
$mail_1->setFrom("$user <$useremail>");
$mail_1->setSubject("$subject");
$mail_1->send(array("$full <$em>"));
}
```

Comment: Why do you have double backticks in your SQL query?

Comment: You're getting the errors in third-party code, not code that you've written yourself? Maybe you should contact the code vendor?